# Proving correctness using Hall's Theorem.

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science

There are four processors $p_1$, $p_2$, $p_3$ and $p_4$ which are designated for six tasks $t_1$, $t_2$, $t_3$, $t_4$, $t_5$ as follows:

$p_1\to \{t_1, t_2\}$,

$p_2\to \{t_1, t_3, t_4\}$,

$p_3\to \{t_3, t_4, t_5\}$, and

$p_4\to \{t_2, t_6\}$.

Using Hall's Theorem how to find whether it is possible to develop a super processor that will serve exactly one task assigned to each of the four processors.

I am looking for a graphical approach.

Comment: p1->t1 p2->t3 p3->t4 p4->t6 is that what you want? To be exact, Hall's Theorem states that for every subset of ${p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4}$ is connected to at least $|S|$ tasks, which is easy to verify here?

Comment: If you search on "system of distinct representatives" you will find many relevant posts.